# Make table buttons go full-width on small screens

Tags: html, css, email

Trying to make a border-based button go full-width on small screens. Needs to work via CSS and HTML because this is for an email which can't use JS.

Any ideas?

Tried using media queries but it didnt work.

P.S. Border buttons are described here: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.link-button {
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  border-radius: 20px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
  background-color: #EB7035; 
  border-top: 12px solid #EB7035; 
  border-bottom: 12px solid #EB7035; 
  border-right: 18px solid #EB7035; 
  border-left: 18px solid #EB7035; 
  display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .inner-table {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="outer-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="inner-table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a class="link-button" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">I am a button</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: you didn't make the button 100% for smaller screens

Comment: Do you really need different behavior on different resolutions? I mean, you may make it wide for everybody or leave as is for mobile too.

Comment: Why aren't you using `button` or `a` without using border trick instead?

Comment: Just set the link to `block` instead of `inline-block` ...

Comment: Can't you give `link-button` to 100% in media query?

Comment: @inarilo Yes I know. That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Anarion Yes it need to be wide on mobile.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Not sure what you mean exactly, I am trying to make a button from HTML and CSS that goes full-width on mobile and is compatible will all major email clients.

Comment: @CBroe This works! Thank you :D

Comment: Not sure why this question got down voted :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, the answer is to set the .link-button class as a block instead of inline-block.

```css
.inner-table {
  text-align: center;
}

.link-button {
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  border-radius: 20px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
  background-color: #EB7035; 
  border-top: 12px solid #EB7035; 
  border-bottom: 12px solid #EB7035; 
  border-right: 18px solid #EB7035; 
  border-left: 18px solid #EB7035; 
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .link-button {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="outer-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="inner-table" width="100%" >
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a class="link-button" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">I am a button</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks to @CBroe who provided this answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add min-width for the smaller screens

Comment: Hello @achraflakhdar and welcome to SO, could you please provide some code as an example and elaborate a bit more your answer ?